# tikz arrow points in wrong direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

In my MWE (see below) the arrow from node P2 to node P3 points in the wrong direction (should be up not down).

I suspect the close proximity of these two nodes could be responsible for this issue, but I don't know how to solve it without changing the two nodes in the last line inside the tikz-picture, which is technically the "wrong" solution in my opinion.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
    positioning,%
    shapes}% TIKZ Bibliotheken

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % x-Achse
        \draw [->] (-0.5,0) -- (9,0)% Linie
            node [right] {Preis};% Label
        % y-Achse
        \draw [->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,9)% Linie
            node [above] {Menge};% Label
        % Graph
        \draw (0,8) -- (3,7)% Linie 1
            node [midway, above, sloped] {Nachfrage};% Label
        \draw [teal] (3,7) -- (5,1)% Linie 2
            node [teal, midway, right] {monopolistischer Bereich};% Label
        \draw (5,1) -- (8,0);% Linie 3
        % Menge
        \draw [teal, dashed] (5,1) -- (5,0)% Linie
            node [below] (M1) {\(M_1\)};% Label
        \draw [teal, dashed] (3,7) -- (3,0)% Linie
            node [below] (M2) {\(M_2\)};% Label
        \draw [->, teal] (M1) -- (M2);
        \draw [red, dashed] (1.5,7.5) -- (1.5,0)% Linie
            node [below] (M3) {\(M_3\)};% Label
        \draw [->, red] (M2) -- (M3);
        % Preise
        \draw [teal, dashed] (5,1) -- (0,1)% Linie
            node [left] (P1) {\(P_1\)};% Label
        \draw [teal, dashed] (3,7) -- (0,7)% Linie
            node [left] (P2) {\(P_2\)};% Label
        \draw [->, teal] (P1) -- (P2);
        \draw [red, dashed] (1.5,7.5) -- (0,7.5)% Linie
            node [left] (P3) {\(P_3\)};% Label
        \draw [->, red] (P2) -- (P3);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
``
```

Comment: The conjecture seems correct. Adding `scale=1.5` shows a full fledged arrow in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the node `P3` and the node `P2` overlap. So the bottom of `P3` is below the top of `P2`. The `\draw` command is drawing from the top edge of `P2` to the bottom edge of `P3`, which is downward.

You can use `(P2.center) -- (P3.center)` to draw from the center of the nodes, but then the arrow must be shortened using `shorten >=` and `shorten <=`. Note that the space after `shorten` is not optional.

I suggest

```
\draw [->, red, shorten >=1.5mm, shorten <=2mm] (P2.center) -- (P3.center);
```

but you can shorten the arrow more if you wish.

[image]